# neo4j optimizing shortestpath large number of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

so I've loaded up a dataset to Neo4j with something like 10 MM nodes. I'm looking to solve the problem of starting with two nodes, look for the shortest path excluding a subset of relationship types. Here is an example of a query attempt:

```
match (p1:PT)-[*]-(p2:PT{src:"8"}),
p=shortestPath((p1)-[*..20]-(p2)) 
with p where p1.src is not null 
and NONE (n in nodes(p) where labels(n) in [["X"],["Y"],["FX","RX"],["RX","FX"]]) 
return p limit 5000
```

The query takes forever (effectively). As I understand it, the query will take all pairs p1, p2 for which there is some relationship, determine the shortest path between each pair, remove the shortest paths which fail the last clause and return up to 5000 such paths if they exist.

So I would like to know if 1) anyone sees an obviously more efficient way of doing this and
2) If I wanted to select the shortest path from those which satisfy that last clause, how would the query be modified? Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MATCH (p2:PT {src:"8"})
MATCH p=shortestPath((p1:PT)-[*..20]-(p2)) 
WHERE p1.src IS NOT NULL
AND none(n in nodes(p) where labels(n) in [["X"],["Y"],["FX","RX"],["RX","FX"]]) 
RETURN p LIMIT 5000;
```

This should be a bit better. `(p1:PT)-[*]-(p2:PT {src: "8"})` will match on **all** paths connected to `p2`, of any length. Also, removing the `WITH` statement will allow for the predicates to be brought into the `shortestPath` criteria.

Is there some other criteria to more narrowly specify `p1`, other than that it has the label `PT` and it's `src` property is not null?

Comment: Thanks William -  still pretty sluggish I'm afraid but your query makes sense.

Comment: Do you have an index on `:PT(src)`?